Are PDEs with different expressions but identical dispersion equations the same?
I was messing around with the Helmholtz equation
$$\nabla^2 \psi + k^2 \psi =0$$
and got to the following PDE
$$\partial_z \psi = \frac{i}{k+k_z}\nabla^2_\perp \psi + ik\psi$$
where $k_z = \sqrt{k^2 - k^2_x-k^2_y}$ and $k_x, k_y, k_z$ are the spatial frequencies from the Fourier transform such that
$$\tilde{\psi}(k_x, k_y, k_z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \psi (x,y,z) \exp(i(k_x x +k_y y + k_z z)dxdydz.$$
If I apply the Fourier transform on the Helmholtz equation I gen the usual
$$k^2 = k^2_x + k^2_y + k^2_y$$
but when I do the same for the second PDE I get the same equation.
What does this say about these PDEs? My main issue is that if I want a unique solution for the Helmholtz equation with initial conditions on a the plane $xOy$, I need $\psi(x,y,0)$ and $\partial_z\psi(x,y,0)$, however, for the second one, it looks like only $\psi(x,y,0)$ is enough, at least from a numerical perspective. This does not sound right to me.
